# Netbeans Platform App with maven fails on bundle.properties change

Tags: java, maven, netbeans, localization, netbeans-platform

I am developing a desktop app using Netbeans platform (7.4). I created the project with maven within the Netbeans wizards. I created a module and a topcomponent within the module - so far so good. However, when I change the bundle file from the properties window for the topcomponent, it does not compile the module correctly and gives the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot find TopComponent with preferredID
```

The new bundle file sure exists within the project - just a folder above of the default one. When I change the bundle to the old one, it works again.

I know that the bundle change from the properties window works, because if I create an app without maven, I can do the change.

Why I try to do this? My app will have several screens, and if a new bundle file is created for each window, localization will be unmanagable. I try to use a single bundle file and put everything in it.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In the properties window in Netbeans of the component you want to change the bundle, Automatic Internalization is check and the Properties Bundle File path is the good one? That's how I've managed to use the same bundle file for many components.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It does not work for Maven-created projects. I can use the same bundle file for non-maven project.

Answer (score 1):

This problem "cannot find TopCoponent with preferredID..." happens frequently when a problem occurs before loading the TopComponent.

A simple example : you try to load something in the constructor that fails (at any depth).

This unexplicit message made me mad more than once !

(answered also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27421091/1579667) )

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not entirely following what you do and why but likely related to issue https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=221781. when compile on save is turned on, the save action doesn't regenerate non class content in annotation processors. you haveto either do clean build (build alone won't cut it) or disable compile on save

Comment: I've already found that bug, tried the solution but unfortunately that is not the case.

Comment: To reproduce the issue, follow these steps: 1- Create a new Netbeans Application from the Maven category. This will create a parent, app and branding project. 2- Create a Netbeans module again from the Maven category. 3- Create a new "Window", a.k.a. topComponent on this module (and add some UI elements) . 4- Run the project (you need to add the module as dependency to the app project and disable test code). 5- Now, create a new bundle.properties file, and point to it on the topComponent properties window. Re-run the app - it will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. It's about automatic code generation.

When I set the text of a component from a bundle, the auto-generated code is in this format:

```
org.openide.util.NbBundle.getMessage({sourceFileName}.class, "{key}")
```

Which means, the bundle.properties and the source file should be on the same package. My purpose was to unify the bundle.properties files and use a single file. For that purpose, I created a bundle.properties file, not within the same package of the source file. I selected the bundle file from the properties window of the editor to use this bundle file. However, the selected bundle path is not reflected to the auto-generated code format - thus it still looks the old path. This code built successfully, but failed to run due to missing resource.

To overcome this, I created a dummy class on the same package with the unified bundle.properties file, and named it as "Resources.java". Then, I modified the auto code generation format as following:

```
org.openide.util.NbBundle.getMessage(Resources.class, "{key}")
```

I need to organize imports after setting this, but it works.

I know my problem is an uncommon one, and the solution is a bit ugly, but I am mislead by the Netbeans editor's properties window. If I can the bundle file there, then the auto code generation should also reflect that change.